Smallest algebra generated by singletons and its topological equivalent
It seems like the smallest algebra containing all singletons of a set $\Omega$ contains all finite and all co-finite subsets of $\Omega$.
This coincides with the union of all open and all closed sets of the co-finite topology on $\Omega$.
Is there some intuition that this connection should bring about? In other words, do any important topological results or properties matter (i.e., have an important equivalent) in the context of measure theory?
Or, perhaps, it should just be considered a coincidence, left alone lest it obstructs developing an independent intuition/understanding of measure theory(?).

Your first statement is correct. This isn't a similarity, it's an identity. So it's rather unclear what kind of intuitive explanation you are looking for.

@RobArthan Thanks for verifying the correctness! You raise a good point. I tried to clarify it in the question.

If you're new to measure theory, then it might be helpful to say that measure spaces feel a bit like topological spaces (and the definition of a measurable function is very like the definition of a continuous function). In cases like your example where the algebras are constructed from finite data, the connection is very close, but things drift apart when you look at things like the real line under its usual topology and measure space structure.

@RobArthan Thanks! Your assessment is spot on, and your answer does offer a great deal of insight :) This kind of direction is actually what I was expecting/hoping for.

You should be careful when comparing topology and measure theory, once you learn how to measure nice subsets, it can happen that sets which are topologically "large" can be "small" in measure theory and vise-versa. However, topology plays a important role in measure theory,  in certain situations of "nice enough" measures, you can approximate your sets by open sets and compact sets. In terms of sigma algebras, the first real connection is the borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ which is generated by open sets. However the structures of a topology and a sigma algebra are quite different.
